# Hardhat Testing error on not getting a value as output

Tags: javascript, testing, ethereum, solidity, hardhat

I'm using hardhat for testing the script was successfully deployed and I got the prices of dai and usdc but when I stated testing I got this error

Error: call revert exception [ See: https://links.ethers.org/v5-errors-CALL_EXCEPTION ] (method="getLatestDaiPrice(address)", data="0x", errorArgs=null, errorName=null, errorSignature=null, reason=null, code=CALL_EXCEPTION, version=abi/5.7.0)

contract:

```
function getLatestDaiPrice(address daiAggregator) external view returns (int) {
  require(daiAggregator != address(0), "Invalid address"); 
  return priceConsumer.getLatestPrice(daiAggregator);
}
```

testscript:

```
it("returns the latest DAI price", async () => {
  let daiAggregator = "0x14866185B1962B63C3Ea9E03Bc1da838bab34C19"; 

  const daiPrice = await priceTracker.getLatestDaiPrice(daiAggregator);
  expect(daiPrice.toNumber()).to.be.a("number");
});
```

Why am I getting this error, and how do I fix this?

Only this test case is failing other 2 cases are passing.

Network used: sepolia